# Why does the second statement follow from the first one?

Tags: metric-spaces

**Theorem**

Let $M$ and $N$ be metric spaces, then the metric space $F_{b}(M,N)$ 
$= \{f:M \to N : \text{f bounded} \}$ is complete if $N$ is complete

**Proof**

Let $\{f_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $F_{b}(M,N)$ 
$= \{f:M \to N : \text{f bounded} \}$. **Then** (why?) for any $m \in M$ the sequence $\{f_k(m)\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cachy sequence in $N$.

I do not understand why the second statement (second sentence) follows from the first.

The metric on the set $F_b(M,N)$ is $d(f,g) = \sup_{m \in M} d_N(f(m),g(m))$

Comment: What is the distance function on $F_{b}(M,n)$?

Comment: arbitrary, i have edited.

Comment: No, its arbitrary. I have edited @BigbearZzz

Comment: What do you mean arbitrary? In order that $F_{b}(M,n)$ be a metric space, a distance function must be given.

Comment: Oh im sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: The metric on the set $F_b(M,N)$ is $d(f,g) = \sup_{m \in M} d_N(f(m),g(m))$ @BigbearZzz

Comment: If that's the case then Catalin's answer seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are working with the following distance: $d(f_j,f_k)=\sup\{d(f_j(m),f_k(m));m\in M\}$. If $\{f_k\}$ is Cauchy, then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exist $N_\epsilon$ such that $d(f_j,f_k)<\epsilon$ for any $j,k\ge N_\epsilon$. This also implies that for any $m\in M$, $d(f_j(m),f_k(m))\le d(f_j,f_k)<\epsilon$ for any $j,k\ge N_\epsilon$.
Hence $\{f_k(m)\}$is Cauchy also.

Comment: No its not, i have edited. Sorry for my left out information.

Comment: The metric on the set $F_b(M,N)$ is $d(f,g) = \sup_{m \in M} d_N(f(m),g(m))$

Comment: Yes. Check the answer now. I

Comment: Yes, this I understand. This was a good explanation. I had missed the definition of the metric on $F_b$